# Content Editable selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to disable selecting text for all elements which a user cannot edit, for example text or images, but I still want to keep it for elements that you can type inside, like inputs or textareas.

To disable text selection, I use the following:

```
* {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

But as I said, this effects all elements, so I tried using this selector:

```
*[contenteditable=false]
```

instead of just *

But this doesn't work apparently for some reason, is there any selector in CSS to detect content-editable elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), which will select on the presence of the [`contenteditable` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content).

What you are actually looking for is a way to *not* select elements which accept input, for which there is no shared selector. You would have to use [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and list all such tags (and possibly include the `contenteditable` attribute selector).

```css
*:not(input):not(textarea):not([contenteditable=""]):not([contenteditable="true"]) {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<input value="input" />
<hr />
<textarea>textarea</textarea>
<hr />
<p>paragraph</p>
<hr />
<p contenteditable>paragraph editable</p>
```

Comment: Cool, but I want the opposite, where elements cannot be edited by the user

Comment: @Murplyx I see, for that you can use `:not`. I've updated the answer.